# Providing class method typedefs from decorator function

Tags: typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

Is it possible to specify types of the arguments passed to the class method from the decorator function? (So when I use the `@OnClient` decorator, the arguments passed to the method will have typedefs without explicitly typing it out. (like `OnPlayerAuth(Player: alt.Player, Done: (..args: any) => void, Data: Object)`))

The first two arguments of the method is always will be an alt.Player instance, and the Done callback function is a void func. The third (Data) argument is an object, with the same properties in the yup object shape and `AuthServerPayload` interface.

```
import yup from 'yup';

import { AuthEvents, AuthServerPayload } from '../../Shared/WebView/Components/Auth';
import { OnClient } from '../Decorators/Events';

class AuthSystem {
  @OnClient(
    AuthEvents.REQUEST_PLAYER_AUTH_SERVER,
    yup.object().shape({
      AuthToken: yup.string().required(),
    })
  )
  private static OnPlayerAuth(Player, Done, Data) {
    
  }
}
```

The decorator function:

```
type ClientCallback = (...args: any) => void;
type ClientFetchMethod = (Player: alt.Player, Done: ClientCallback, ...args: any) => void;

export const OnClient = (event: string, bodyDto?: yup.AnySchema<any>) => {
  return function (target: Object, key: string | symbol, descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<any>) {
    const originalMethod = descriptor.value as ClientFetchMethod;

    alt.onClient(event, async (SourcePlayer: alt.Player, Payload?: IFetchPayload) => {
      try {
        let { __Params, Data } = Payload;

        if (!__Params || !__Params.ReturnCode) throw Error('No ReturnCode has been provided!');

        if (bodyDto) {
          Data = await bodyDto.validate(Data, {});
          if (!Data) throw Error('Invalid data schema');
        }

        const CallbackFunc = function (...args: any[]) {
          SourcePlayer.emit(Data.__Params.ReturnCode, args);
        };

        originalMethod(SourcePlayer, CallbackFunc, Data);
      } catch (error) {
        alt.logError(`Player ${SourcePlayer.name} (${SourcePlayer.id}) failed data validation on event '${event}'.`);
        alt.logError('Data given by the client: ');
        alt.logError(JSON.stringify(Payload));
        alt.logError(error);
      }
    });

    return descriptor;
  };
};
```

Comment: You may validate the type is same but not define afaik. Decorators are ignored when making types, as they have no way to change the type, that's the point.